# Android Studio - Can't see my files in Project window

Tags: android-studio

I cannot see any files except for **the last one i created** in my project window. I do not remember doing anything specific when this problem occurred. Below is a picture of how it looks

[image]

However, if I click **Sync project with Gradle files** or **restart Android Studio**, I can see the files for **less than a second**. Below is another picture of how this looks

[image]

Some of my files are in these folders and some files are in com.[exampleName].

**The files are still there when I click "Show in explorer"** on the com.[exampleName] folder

**How can I fix this?**

**EDIT**

I can't see my files when I click "Project" or "Android, **but I can see them if I click "Packages"**

Answer (score 0):

The soloution was pretty simple. I am using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) which lets me group files into a folder. I had accidentally clicked "Group" on my com.[example] folder which messed it up. Ungrouping this folder solved the problem.